# Why can I only open an rtsp capture from python opencv2 if I input the connection string directly from the command prompt?

Tags: python, opencv, camera, rtsp, read-eval-print-loop

This is one of the strangest bugs I've ever encountered. I have the following python code:

```py
import cv2 as cv

def newCamera():
  return frameIterator(
    'rtsp://admin:p4ssword@172.16.20.59:544/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1'
  )

# return an infinite iterator of frames from an amcrest camera
def frameIterator(rtspConnStr):
  cap = cv.VideoCapture(rtspConnStr)
  return (
    cap.read() for _ in iter(int, 1)
  )
```

In the python REPL, if I do:

```py
>>> import amcrest
>>> amcrest.frameIterator('rtsp://admin:p4ssword@172.16.20.59:544/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1')
<generator object frameIterator.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x7fe5ed350350>
>>> amcrest.newCamera()
[tcp @ 0x29fb180] Connection to tcp://172.16.20.59:544?timeout=0 failed: Connection refused
```

I cannot explain this behavior. Comparing the rtsp connection strings yields `True`. My only guess is that they're being marshalled differently by `ctypes` but I can't figure it out. Any help? Thanks!

EDIT: this is all in a file named `amcrest.py`, thus the `import amcrest` :)

Comment: maybe check the `type()` of those strings. apart from that, I'd say your hypothesis is wrong, i.e. it's the REPL affecting things, not the strings affecting things.

Comment: I’ve done type and both return str as expected. I think you’re right on that though.